# Using WP_Query for categories instead of get_terms

Tags: wp-query, terms

I have managed to get all parent categories from Woocommerce with this function

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'    => 0
) );
```

But I haven't managed to do the same with **WP_Query**. Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I do the same - getting a list of categories from
   Woocommerce - with WQ_Query
2. Is it recommended to use WP_Query over get_terms?

Thanks.

Comment: `WP_Query` is for querying posts and only returns post objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$category_detail=get_the_category(get_the_ID());//$post->ID
foreach($category_detail as $cd)
{
    $name_cat=$cd->cat_name;
    $id_cat=$cd->term_id;
}
```

try now this code

Comment: I need to get a list of all/parent categories not a category for the_post.